# File-upload Widget for Yii2 install

Tags: php, file-upload, yii2, blueimp

For multiple image installation we are using `yii2-file-upload-widget` But when I install with the help of composer and run this command:

```
$ composer require 2amigos/yii2-file-upload-widget:~1.0
```

It gives me an error message:

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [66.235.194.119](http://66.235.194.119/Screenshot%20from%202016-10-03%2014:33:12.png))</sub>

I also added manually but when I added manually its showing error message:

> Class 'dosamigos\fileupload\FileUpload' not found

Comment: That information error "Class 'dosamigos\fileupload\FileUpload' not found" cause you not succesfully install the extension. You can see details for instalation this below. https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-file-upload-widget

Comment: @NurChalikAzhar I followed this link but when I run this command "composer require 2amigos/yii2-file-upload-widget:~1.0"  its showing which I already  added as as  screenshot then I added manually then its showing   this error "Class 'dosamigos\fileupload\FileUpload'

Comment: Probably if you added manually this widget you have to set the correct namespaces i suppose